# Force Download Corrupt File Rewritten File Content

Tags: php, html, header, download, mime-types

Another problem with PHP force download.  It was working and then i did something and now its not.

Here we go (there are if statements for each file type I accept but just showing one should be enough to help diagnose the problem):

```
$string1 = 'home/myhost/aboveroot/reviews/';
$string2 = $username;
$string3 = '/';
$string4 = $filename;
$file= $string1.$string2.$string3.$string4;
$ext = strtolower (end(explode('.', $filename)));
//Finding MIME type
    if ($ext = pdf){
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename= '$filename'");
        header('Content-type: application/pdf');
        readfile('$file');
```

What ends up happening is that it forces a file download with the correct file name and of the correct extension.  It doesn't trigger a corrupt file error of any sort.  However, when I open the file the content is missing.  If its a word document it will refuse to open.  If its a text document the **text will be changed to a bunch of php errors as follows:**

**Warning**:  readfile($file) [function.readfile]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **/home/myhost/public_html/wwww.mydomain.com/pagethatforceddownload.php** on line **68**

Then it gives this error for each line with a header (even those contained in if clauses that should not be meeting their conditions:

**Warning**:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/myhost/public_html/wwww.mydomain.com/pagethatforceddownload.php:68) in **/home/myhost/public_html/wwww.mydomain.com/pagethatforceddownload.php** on line **69**

I'm really lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I finally get everything on my site working and BAM, I realize that im having this huge mess of a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is wrong :

```
if ($ext = pdf){
```

It should be :

```
if ($ext == "pdf"){
```

And you could add :

```
if($ext == "pdf" && file_exists($file)) {
```

to be sure that you get a valid file.

And this is wrong too :

```
readfile('$file');
```

It should be :

```
readfile($file);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. I am always a bit confused about when to use " or ' neither.  Any advice on some basic reading that would clarify.

Comment: With simple quote, php will never look if there is a variable or not in the string, so 'a $variable' will always give 'a $variable' even if you declared a $variable before.

With double quotes, php will search variable in the string and replace them with values. "a $variable" will become "a value_of_variable".

Look at http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php for more info.